# Deleting a subclassed overlapping JPA entity in a JOINED Strategy

Tags: jpa, overlapping

I want to model something like the following

A super class User with JOINED inheritance strategy. 
User has two subclasses HumanUser and BotUser. 
HumanUser has two subclasses NonAdminUser and AdminUser 
NonAdminUser has two subclasses Citizen and Operator 
AdminUser has two subclasses SiteAdministrator and UserAdministrator 
BotUser has one subclass System

I want to model an overlapping hierarchy where a user with a given userId can be one or more of Citizen, Operator, SiteAdministrator and UserAdministrator.

How can this be achieved in JPA?

In my application, after creating one leaf-level entity (say Citizen), when I want to create another overlapped entity, an error is thrown saying due to primary key constraint, persistence cannot be done.

Also, if overlapping is possible, how to delete just the information at the leaf-level. For e.g. only delete Citizen specific data, but let SiteAdministrator data remain.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Do not put the new class on top of the existing hierarchy, and it is technically not possible for a subclass of `User` to be both a `Citizen` and a `System`, since Java does not support multiple inheritance.

I would implement a class like `UserRoles` with a `ManyToMany` relation to `User` (favouring composition over inhertance). Then you can remove a single subclass of `User` from the `UserRoles` and from the DB without unwanted side-effects.

```
@ManyToMany
private List<User> roles = new ArrayList<User>();
```

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not required as a `Citizen` & a `System` both inherit from `User` and as such are overlapping specialization of a `User`. Maybe its an issue of differences in object modeling and table/relation modeling. The requirement is to model `UserType` and `Role`. A 'UserType' can have one or more 'Roles'. Also there are specific relations between differnt user types. E.g. A `UserAdministrator` can manage `Citizen` or `Operator` and there is a requirement to capture domain attributes for these various relationships.

Comment: @RKSinha - do I understand correctly that the `User` class corresponds to the `Role` of your requirement and you are thinking about how to implement the `UserType`? If so, then it is important if the `UserType` is a composition of `Role`. If it is, then it is sufficiently defined by it's roles and may be represented by a single type with no inhertiance, but erhaps with a `String` attribute to make the type human-readable. The fact that `Roles` have relationships with attributes should not be an issue.

Comment: The fact that you are using joined inheritance is not an issue neither. If you delete a single `Citizen`, it will delete only the relevant rows from the tables `NonAdminUser`, `HumanUser` and `User`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am changing the modeling and now using composition. Now a `User` has zero or more `Profile`s and is allotted one or more `Role`s